# Can I call my Echo Dot from the Alexa app on my iPhone?

Tags: smart-home, alexa, amazon-echo

Can you call the Echo Dot from the iPhone Alexa app? They are both registered to me.  When I try it rings, but will not allow me to pick up.  I have the latest iOS on an iPhone 7 Plus and the latest Dot.  When I call myself, the Dot rings but won't pick-up when I say "Alexa, answer call". I've tried various terms to get her to answer but she either doesn't respond or says there is no call.  My app continues to ring until it times out.

Comment: You should be able to, as far as I know. What are you saying to pick up the call, and are there any errors?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Dan G. Which iOS version does your phone have? You'll need at least 9.0. Anyways, we'll need a few more information to properly answer your question. Are you in the US? What Dot do you have? Which Alexa app?

Comment: @Dan When you call Alexa, it should look [like this](https://youtu.be/h5wmJbhyhC4?t=72). Does the ring light up blue when you say "Alexa," while being called? Does it then go green again once you say "answer"?

Answer (score 3):

Technically not the answer you were looking for, but the **drop in** feature that JUST came out will allow you to establish a call without anybody having to say answer call on your echo.